# How to define an animation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

I'm looking for a way to let a variable equal an animation. So that later I can refer to it and change the speed of the animation.

```
   // Image Animation
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0.8, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear], animations: {
    self.image.frame = CGRect(x: 250, y: 1200, width: 45, height: 45)

    }, completion: nil)
```

// Function Speed Check

```
func speedcheck() {

    if score > 25 {

        Image.stopAnimating()

        // Image Animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.8, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear], animations: {
            self.Image.frame = CGRect(x: 250, y: 1200, width: 45, height: 45)

        }, completion: nil)

        UIView.commitAnimations()

            }        
}
```

"Image.stopAnimating()"

As shown in the example, this line does not stop the animation that was previously executed above, because it does not know what to cease. Therefore, I'm wondering how to define the initial animation, so from there I can increase the speed.

What's the best way to speed up an animation when the score is greater than 25?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should add a minimal example to the question. And you should be more specific in what exactly is your problem. --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve should be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to assign the animation to a variable. I don't think that is even possible.

By speeding up the animation, you mean reducing the duration of the animation. 
To do that just hold the **animationDuration** value in a global variable say **animationSpeed**.

Just use this **animationSpeed** variable value in the **UIView.animate()** method for the duration param.

Declare a global speed param:

```
var animationSpeed = TimeInterval.init(5.0)
```

Use this in your UIView.animate() method:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: animationSpeed) { 

}
```

Now you can change this animationSpeed param value when a condition is satisfied:

```
if condition {
 self.animationSpeed = TimeInterval.init(2.5)
}
```

When you give the animation options as .repeat, the values captured initially while entering the animation block will be used throughout the animation. This is not something that we want. Use something like this

```
func animateView() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.speed, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {

            // Your animation

        }, completion: { flag in

            if flag {
              if speed > 25 {
                self.speed = TimeInterval.init(2.0)
                self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
              }

                self.animateView() 
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: So do you mean, defining animationSpeed, then apply an Int value to it, in the new updated animation code?

Comment: **withDuration** at the first line needs to be changed to **animationSpeed**. And why are you setting the animationSpeed param inside a animation block of a animation block??

Comment: UIView.animate(withDuration: animationSpeed, delay: 0.8, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear], animations: {
    self.image.frame = CGRect(x: 250, y: 1200, width: 45, height: 45)
    //Call the method to check speed and update speed/duration
    }, completion: nil)

Comment: // Image Animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationSpeed, delay: 0.8, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear], animations: {
            self.Image.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 850, width: 45, height: 45)
            
            if self.score >= 25 {
                self.animationSpeed = TimeInterval.init(1.2)
                
            }
            
        }, completion: nil)

Comment: The image still does not speed for some reason.

Comment: The image only speeds up when the game is over and you click try again. For some reason the initial start does not speed up the images.

Comment: Try this. In the completion block check if the speed has changed. If it is greater than 25 stop the animation. Change the speed param and call the animation block again. Since the AnimationTypeOption is .repeat, the initial recorded values will be used in the loop of animation. The updated value won't be considered. Hold on, I ll update my answer.

Comment: To stop the animation would: image.stopAnimating() appropriate?

Comment: // Image Animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationSpeed, delay: 0.8, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear], animations: {
            self.Image.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 850, width: 45, height: 45)
            
            if self.score > 25 {
                self.Image.stopAnimating()
                self.animationSpeed = TimeInterval.init(0.7)
                self.Image.startAnimating()
                
            }
            
        }, completion: nil)

Comment: @Jacob Check the updated answer. I have added a code snippet at the bottom. that should do the trick.

Comment: @Jacob Change the param names as per your code. And what is the error that you are facing with it?

Comment: View controller has no member of 'animateView()'. The last line of code.

Comment: @Jacob animateView() is the function posted above. Did you copy the entire method posted above or just the animation block??

Comment: I changed it to my relevant function name. Self.speedCheck(), which is fine. However, now the image only repeats once, and doesn't animate again.

Comment: You have to place the UIView.animate() block inside a method. In the completion block of the animation this method needs to be called again to repeat the animation. The method name for me in the above snippet is animateView(). Am calling this method in the animation block to repeat the animation. Please make this change.

Comment: // Image Animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.animationSpeed, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            self.Image.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 850, width: 45, height: 45)
            
        }, completion: { flag in
            
            if flag {
                if self.score > 25 {
                    self.animationSpeed = TimeInterval.init(0.8)
                    self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
                }
                
                self.speedcheck()
                
            }
        })

Comment: Animation still does not repeat.

Comment: Any further suggestions?

Comment: Is this appropriate?

Comment: func speedcheck() {
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.animationSpeed, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            
            self.Image.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 850, width: 45, height: 45)
                
        }, completion: { flag in
            
            if flag {
                if self.score > 25 {
                    self.animationSpeed = TimeInterval.init(2.0)
                    self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
                }
                
                self.speedcheck()
            }
        })
    
    }

Comment: Still not repeating.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: @Jacob I believe the animation is repeating. The problem is with the property "frame" you are tying to animate. After the first call to animation completes, the frame is set to the value specified in the animation block. Are you resetting this frame anywhere else?? If not, there is nothing to animate in the next cycle, because frame is already set to that value.

Comment: On the storyboard my image is at position (163, 3), and in the animation block is it animating from (150, 850). I have tried changing these values, they still do not work.

Comment: Any way to try and diagnose the specified animation frame?